# Compare two arrays with the same value but with a different order

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have 2 nsarray, with the same values but in different order.

NSArray * array1 = {0,1,2,3}
NSArray * array2 = {2,3,1,0}

I need a method to determinate if two arrays have the same values in a different order.

Kind of

```
-(BOOL) isSameValues:(NSArray*)array1 and:(NSArray*)array2;
```

Comment: sort em and then iterate over and see if every element matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([[NSSet setWithArray:array1] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithArray:array2]]) {
    // the objects are the same
}
```

Comment: This would consider `[@1, @2, @2]` and `[@1, @1, @2]` as equal.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `NSCountedSet` for that purpose:

```
- (BOOL)isSameValues:(NSArray*)array1 and:(NSArray*)array2
{
    NSCountedSet *set1 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:array1];
    NSCountedSet *set2 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:array2];
    return [set1 isEqualToSet:set2];
}
```

`NSCountedSet` is a collection of different objects, where each object has an associated counter with it. Therefore the result for

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@0,@1,@2,@3];
NSArray *array2 = @[@2,@3,@1,@0];
```

is `YES`, but for

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@1,@1,@3,@3];
NSArray *array2 = @[@3,@3,@3,@1];
```

the result is `NO`.

Comment: I wonder if just sorting arrays and then comparing would be same speed, or potentially faster?

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko: I *assume* that inserting the array elements into the counted set (using the `hash` method to identify identical elements) is faster than actually sorting all elements (or at least not slower). But I can't tell you for sure. - In any case, this would work with arrays of arbitrary elements, which might be not comparable.

Comment: I have heard already many stories on the speed of arrays VS. `NSSet`. And I don't know which is to believe, but as far as comparison goes, this is very much correct. Learnt something today. +1.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** this will not work if arrays have duplicate elements!

You could create two `NSSet`s with those arrays and the compare them.

```
NSArray * array1 = @[@0,@1,@2,@3];
NSArray * array2 = @[@2,@3,@1,@0];

NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:array1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:array2];

NSLog(@"result %@", [set1 isEqualToSet:set2] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: This would consider `[@1, @2, @2]` and `[@1, @1, @2]` as equal.

Comment: @MartinR: It is not clear that that is incorrect behavior. It does contain the same values. If the number of occurrences is relevant, just make it an NSCountedSet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take total no of elements. Have a counter. And put double 'for loop' to parse through each and every element of each other. Increment the counter at each matching.
Note :  This is valid when all elements are unique.

If different or you don't know, sort them and match one to one.

Answer (score 0):

An other way would be to use a `NSHashTable`.

```
- (BOOL)array:(NSArray *)array1 containsTheSameObjectsAsArray:(NSArray *)array2 {
    if (array1.count != array2.count) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSHashTable *table = [[NSHashTable alloc] initWithOptions:NSHashTableWeakMemory 
                                                     capacity:array1.count];
    for (NSObject *object in array1) {
        [table addObject:object];
    }
    for (NSObject *object in array2) {
        if (![table containsObject:object]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
   return YES;
}
```

Note that `NSHashTable` requires iOS 6+