# How many occurrence of each item appears in a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray with some NSNumber :

```
{1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2}
```

I would like to know how many occurrence of each number appears in the list.

```
Ex :  
1 = 2  
2 = 3  
3 = 2  
6 = 1
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried and why it is not working. Simple asking "I need", "Give me" is not what this website is about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put all the items into a `NSCountedSet`.

```
NSCountedSet* countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];

for (NSNumber* number in countedSet) {
   NSLog(@"%@ = %u", number, [countedSet countForObject:number]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know NSCountedSet. It's very useful.

Comment: @cmi: You should know it from the answers to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709494/compare-two-arrays-with-the-same-value-but-with-a-different-order :-)