# Comparing two arrays ignoring order

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, comparison, nsarray

In the class `NSArray`, there's a method `isEqualToArray:` which compares two arrays and indicates whether they match or not.

I've two arrays which have elements in different order. For example:

```
NSMutableArray* arr1 = [@[@"one", @"two", @"three"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray* arr2 = [@[@"three", @"one", @"two"] mutableCopy];

BOOL same = [arr1 isEqualToArray:arr2];
NSLog(@"%d", same);
```

In above example, even though `arr1` and `arr2` have same the elements, `isEqualToArray:` is returning `NO`. How can I compare two arrays as mentioned above without iterating through each element in a `for`/`while` loop?

Comment: See MartinR's clever answer to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709494/compare-two-arrays-with-the-same-value-but-with-a-different-order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NSSet` and then compare.

```
NSSet *set1=[NSSet setWithArray:arr1];
NSSet *set2=[NSSet setWithArray:arr2];

BOOL same=[set1 isEqualToSet:set2];
```

EDIT:

If you have duplicates in arr1 and arr2, then use :

```
NSCountedSet *set1=[NSCountedSet setWithArray:arr1];
NSCountedSet *set2=[NSCountedSet setWithArray:arr2];

BOOL same=[set1 isEqualToSet:set2];
```

Comment: Note that this only works if it is guaranteed that there are no duplicates in either array. An `NSCountedSet` should take care of things if there could be duplicate values.

Comment: With your method wouldn't the arrays (one, two, one, three) and (three, two, one) be equal? Since each element of a Set is different.

Comment: @Levi Correct. This is why `NSCountedSet` should be used instead of `NSSet`.

Comment: @rmaddy ops, didn't see your comment when I wrote mine :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you sort both arrays, and compare the results with the method you've tried.

Comment: This would work only if all elements are comparable, it would e.g. fail if the array contains both strings and numbers, or arbitrary objects that don't have a compare method.

Comment: @MartinR it is possible, but I've seen noone who wanted to compare 2 arrays with multiple data types. How would you compare them in that case?

Comment: All objects implement `hash` and `isEqual` (and that is what `[NSSet setWithArray:...]` or better `[NSCountedSet setWithArray:...]` uses), so that method works with arbitrary objects.