# Check if elements in two arrays are same irrespective of index

Tags: arrays, swift, set, swift3

Suppose if I have two arrays - `array1` and `array2`

```
let array1 = ["abc","pqr","xyz"]
let array2 = ["pqr", "xyz", "abc"]
```

Then I want result as array1 is equal to array2.

Also if my array has duplicate elements

```
let array1 = ["abc","pqr","xyz"]
let array2 = ["pqr", "xyz", "abc", "abc", "xyz"]
```

Then I want result as array1 is NOT equal to array2.

after searching I have found [Compare two arrays with the same value but with a different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709494/compare-two-arrays-with-the-same-value-but-with-a-different-order/15710166#15710166)

but it is in Objective C and `isEqualToSet`is not there in Swift3

Answer (score 3):

Using counted sets as in [Compare two arrays with the same value but with a different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709494/compare-two-arrays-with-the-same-value-but-with-a-different-order/15710166#15710166) works in Swift 
as well:

```
let set1 = NSCountedSet(array: array1)
let set2 = NSCountedSet(array: array2)
print(set1 == set2)
```

This works well for strings, numbers, and other values which 
are mapped to corresponding Foundation types `NSString`, `NSNumber`,  etc.
It might give unexpected results when used with custom structs.

For a pure Swift solution, count the number of occurrences of each 
element in the arrays:

```
func countMap<T: Hashable>(array: [T]) -> [T: Int] {
    var dict = [T: Int]()
    for elem in array {
        dict[elem] = (dict[elem] ?? 0) + 1
    }
    return dict
}
```

and compare the resulting dictionaries:

```
print(countMap(array: array1) == countMap(array: array2))
```

Alternatively – if the array elements are `Comparable` – 
compare the sorted arrays:

```
print(array1.sorted() == array2.sorted())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing in Swift using `Set` and the `==` operator.