# Swift compare 2 array of type [int] without guaranteed order

Tags: arrays, swift

I make app for performing tests. For check for valid answer i have array of correct answers, of type [Int]. It may be, for example, [1, 5, 10].

Also i have array of questions id's  that user entered, also [Int] type.

Now i have to somehow compare that arrays. But, [1,5,10] should be equal to [10,1,5] and [5,1,10], etc., because order is not guaranteed. How to achieve that?

Comment: what happens when there are duplicates?

Comment: And if your need to deal with duplicate values in the array then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883818/check-if-elements-in-two-arrays-are-same-irrespective-of-index is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function that returns true if an array contains all elements of your array and only those elements, you can use below Array Extension. If the length of the two arrays isn't the same or if one of the elements in your array isn't present in the other array, the function returns false, otherwise it returns true.

```
let array1 = [1,5,10]
let array2 = [5,10,1]
let array3 = [10,1,5]
let otherArray = [2,1,5,10]
let anotherArray = [2,3,5]

extension Array where Element == Int {
    func isUnorderedEqual(to array: [Element])->Bool{
        if self.count == array.count {
            for element in self {
                if array.index(of: element) == nil {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

print(array1.isUnorderedEqual(to: array2)) //true
print(array1.isUnorderedEqual(to: array3)) //true
print(array1.isUnorderedEqual(to: otherArray)) //false
print(array1.isUnorderedEqual(to: anotherArray)) //false
```

Comment: what happens when there are duplicates?

Comment: If the duplicates exist in both arrays, it returns true, otherwise false. Since the question didn't specify the case of duplicates, I didn't specify it either.

Comment: duplicate Question :)

Comment: This is really suboptimal... `O(N^2)`. A set-based solution can do this is in `O(4*n)`

Comment: Since OP didn't specify what to do with duplicate elements, I didn't want to use `Set`, which would discard all duplicates automatically, but you are right, an `NSCountedSet` based solution could be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter for any correct answers not in the list of answers and look if any such item exists.

```
let correctAnswers: [Int] = [1, 5, 10]

func validate(answers: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return answers.filter({ answer in !correctAnswers.contains(answer) }).isEmpty
}

validate(answers: [10, 1, 5])
```

Comment: what happens when there are duplicates?

Comment: Given two lists of the same size such as OP uses, then when there are duplicates, `answers` will obviously have items not in the `correctAnswers` list ...