# How to get list of different (un-common) items of 2 arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This question is similliar to [my other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439289/how-to-get-list-of-common-elements-of-2-array-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment52743732_32439289)

I have 2 arrays:

```
fruitsArray = ["apple", "mango", "blueberry", "orange"]
vegArray = ["tomato", "potato", "mango", "blueberry"]
```

How can I get the uncommon elements of `fruitsArray` comparing to `vegArray`

```
Expected Output = ["apple", orange]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert arrays to Set and use subtract() function to get what you want

```
   let fruitsArray = ["apple", "mango", "blueberry", "orange"]
   let vegArray = ["tomato", "potato", "mango", "blueberry"]

   let set1 = Set(fruitsArray)
   let set2 = Set(vegArray)

   let filter = Array(set1.subtract(set2))
   println(filter) //[apple, orange]
```

Comment: For Swift 4.2 I had to use 'subtracting' instead of 'subtract' like this: let filter = Array(set1.subtracting(set2))

Answer (score 3):

One line

```
let fruitsArray = ["apple", "mango", "blueberry", "orange"]
let vegArray = ["tomato", "potato", "mango", "blueberry"]

let answer = fruitsArray.filter{ item in !vegArray.contains(item) }

print("\(answer)") //  ["apple", "orange"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a couple of difficulties with this operation. First off, there's a difference between the two things you could be asking for: either "difference" or "subtraction". Difference would return the elements that aren't in both arrays, so for instance:

```
let fruitsArray = ["apple", "mango", "blueberry", "orange"]
let vegArray = ["tomato", "potato", "mango", "blueberry"]

difference(fruitsArray, vegArray) // ["apple", "orange", "tomato", "blueberry"]
```

That doesn't seem to be what you're asking for, but it's worth bearing in mind.

The second is a "subtraction", which would yield your expected result. There's one more thing to bear in mind about this. The obvious one-liner:

```
fruitsArray.filter{ !vegArray.contains($0) }
// ["apple", "orange"]
```

Is quadratic. No issue if performance isn't important, but it's easily avoidable, using a `Set`. Now, you could convert both, and use the normal `Set` methods, but that's unnecessary. Converting to a `Set` is O(n) (I think, I'm not actually sure), but you're going to have to iterate through the set from `fruitsArray` anyway, and convert it back to an array in the end. The only advantage of a `Set` is that is has an O(1) `contains` method - so you only need to convert the this that you're using `contains` on. The most efficient way, I think, is:

```
let vSet = Set(vegArray)
fruitsArray.filter { m in !vSet.contains(m) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Powerful functional one-liner:

```
// Swift 1.2
let differenceResult = fruitsArray.filter({!contains(vegArray, $0)})

// Swift 2.0
let differenceResult = fruitsArray.filter(!vegArray.contains)
```

and obviously for your other question, simply remove the `!`:

```
// Swift 1.2
let intersectionResult = fruitsArray.filter({contains(vegArray, $0)})

// Swift 2.0
let intersectionResult = fruitsArray.filter(vegArray.contains)
```