# How to remove common items from two struct arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have two struct arrays and I want to remove common items from one of them. My struct:

```
struct PeopleSelectItem {
    var name = ""
    var id = ""
    var added = false
}
```

My arrays:

```
var people : [PeopleSelectItem] = []
var selectedPeople : [PeopleSelectItem] = []
```

I want to remove items from people array if they exist (compare by id) on selectedPeople array.

I tried several array filtering and converting to set but none of them worked. What can I do here?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to previous SO Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439289/how-to-get-list-of-common-elements-of-2-array-in-swift

Comment: Did you try creating a operator  in your model something like `func ==(lhs: PeopleSelectItem, rhs: PeopleSelectItem) -> [PeopleSelectItem] {
    lhs.id == rhs.id //and filter array
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Get an array of all `id`s in selectedPeople

  ```
    let selectedPeopleIDs = selectedPeople.map(\.id)
  ```
- Filter the items whose id is not in the array

  ```
    let filteredPeople = people.filter { !selectedPeopleIDs.contains($0.id) }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

If you know that people equal each other if the id is the same then you can conform your struct to the `Equatable` protocol and you can use the array filter method.

```
struct PeopleSelectItem : Equatable {
    var name = ""
    var id = ""
    var added = false
}

func ==(lhs: PeopleSelectItem, rhs: PeopleSelectItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

func filterPeople() {
    //swift 2, 3:
    people = people.filter{!selectedPeople.contains($0)}

    //swift older versions:
    people = people.filter{!contains(selectedPeople, $0)}
}
```

Comment: instead of using filter function again, is it sensible to create a new operator that returns the filtered result model?

Answer (score 1):

If `people` might have a significant amount of entries, performance should be considered. So, instead of searching with an n^2 algorithm, you should make use of Swifts dictionary and the corresponding hash-search to find items.

If `Id` is unique for `people` then I would store them in a dictionary like:

```
    var peopleDict: [String:PeopleSelectItem] = [:]()
```

You can easily convert from the array you have to this dictionary:

```
    people.foreach {peopleDict[$0.id] = $0}
```

With this dictionary it's very easy to delete single entries:

```
    selectedPeople.foreach {peopleDict.remove($0.id)}
```

Optionally to switch back to an array for `people` you just say:

```
    let filteredPeople = peopleDict.values as [PeopleSelectItem]
```

Remarks

1. I assumed, that `selectedPeople` is smaller then the base of all `people`. If this is not the case, you should pu `selectedPeople` in a dictionary.
2. did I say I like this Spark like api? I think I do so.
3. I just wrote that code from top of my mind. If it is not completely syntactically correct let me know and I correct it.