# Determine whether array contains one or more elements of another array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-places-api, contains

I have the following code which returns places near the user's current location

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation

struct GlobalVariables {
    static var acceptedEstablishments = ["bakery", "bar", "cafe", "food", "meal_takeaway", "meal_delivery", "night_club", "restaurant", "school", "university"]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    // Add a pair of UILabels in Interface Builder, and connect the outlets to these variables.
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    // Add a UIButton in Interface Builder, and connect the action to this function.
    @IBAction func getCurrentPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {

        placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
                for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods {
                    let place = likelihood.place
                    // only return places that are relevant to me
                    for placeType in place.types {
                        if (GlobalVariables.acceptedEstablishments.contains(placeType)) {
                            print("Current place name: \(place.name)")
                            print("Place type: \(placeType)")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`place.types` in my callback function at the bottom returns an array of strings for each place instance, which looks something like this:

`["health", "point_of_interest", "establishment"]`

I have a global array of strings which also contains tags such as `bakery`, `bar`, etc.

When the user presses a button, the callback function is triggered and returns places based on the nearby location.

The output looks something like this:

```
Current place name: LOCAL SUPERMARKET
Place type: food
Current place name: LOCAL GRILL
Place type: cafe
Current place name: LOCAL GRILL
Place type: food
Current place name: LOCAL SCHOOL
Place type: school
Current place name: LOCAL TAKEAWAY
Place type: meal_takeaway
Current place name: LOCAL TAKEAWAY
Place type: restaurant
Current place name: LOCAL TAKEAWAY
Place type: food
```

The same establishment is repeated multiple times because a single establishment has more than one tag associated with it.

For example:

The returned array for `place.types` for `LOCAL TAKEAWAY` is: `["meal_takeaway", "restaurant", "food"]`

and because my `GlobalVariables.acceptedEstablishments` array contains all three of those strings, the `print` command will be executed three times.

How can this code be amended so that it only displays the establishment once, if the `place.types` array contains one or more of the matching strings? I can't seem to get my head around a solution.

Comment: NSSet ? NSSet where are you? Please use NSSet

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I'm not sure what that is. Please could you provide me with an example of how to use NSSet/ what it's for? I assume it has something to do with arrays but the Array documentation on the apple website mentions nothing about it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array Thanks in advance. I'm new to Swift but always looking to learn

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439289/how-to-get-list-of-common-elements-of-2-array-in-swift
better than NSSet. NSSet allows getting common objects from two collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift Array class allows duplicate items. The Set class does not. You can create an extension on Array that has a method uniqueItems that strips away duplicates. Note that the items in the array have to be Hashable in order for this to work.

Below is the extension. (Not my code - taken from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array))

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    var uniqueItems: Array  {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return flatMap { set.insert($0).inserted ? $0 : nil }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The key is using `Set` which will not have duplicates. `Set` is a collection class which can be used similarly to arrays. You can iterate over it, and it has `count`, `map`, `filter`, `contains`, etc.

```
let acceptedPlaces: Set = ["home", "pub", "hospital"]
let availablePlaces: Set = ["home", "pub", "mountains"]
let inBoth = acceptedPlaces.intersection(availablePlaces) // ["home", "pub"]
```

You can easily create `Set`s from `Array`s `let someSet = Set(someArray)` and the other way round `let someArray = Array(someSet)`. You might also want to take a look at the following functions of `Set`: `union`, `substract`, `isSuperSet`, `isSubset`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use sets:

```
if !Set(place.types).intersection(GlobalVariables.acceptedEstablishments).isEmpty
{
  // there is at least one common element
}
```

If you can afford to make GlobalVariables.acceptedEstablishments a Set, then the condition would be more efficient and could be written as :

```
if !GlobalVariables.acceptedEstablishments.intersection(places.types).isEmpty
{
  // there is at least one common element
}
```

In either cases places.types does not need to be a set itself.

Answer (score 1):

### Using [isDisjoint(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/eventmodifiers/isdisjoint(with:)):

```
if !Set(place.types).isDisjoint(GlobalVariables.acceptedEstablishments) {
    // There is at least one common element
}
```