# Complicated filtering involving array and object with array member

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, filtering

I have two arrays

```
let badContents = ["b1", "b2"]
let things: [Thing] = ...
```

where a Thing has its own contents, like this

```
print(things[0].contents)
// ["g1", "b1", "b2"]
```

I wanted to do something like the below, where I would get an array of type `Thing` whose elements had contents that did not overlap with another array, `badContents`

```
func filteredThings() -> [Thing] {
    return things.filter({ (thing) -> Bool in {
        return // thing.contents and badContents do not share any elements
    }()
    })
}
```

Thus, I would get a result like this

```
let things = [Thing(name: "1", contents: ["g1", "b2"), Thing(name: "2", contents: ["g1", "g2"])]

let goodThings = filteredThings() // removes Thing named "1" because its contents contain "b2"

for goodThing in goodThings {
    print(goodThing.name)
    // "2"
}
```

Comment: [How to get list of common elements of 2 arrays in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32439289)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks but thats not actually what I want to do. The main difference is that I am trying to get a result of type `[Thing]` who has a _member property_ that is comparable to the other array. The linked question would work maybe if my `badContents` was of type `[Thing]`

Comment: @rdk: In your filter method you want to check if *"thing.contents and badContents do not share any elements"* – in other words, if these 2 arrays have no common elements. Therefore  the above link should help to find a solution.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I now see how to use that in my solution!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted. P.S. that `arrayOfCommonElements` is a really crappy O(N^2) solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't make much difference for performance (unless `badThings` is large, or `contents` is both large and "bad things" are common), but I'd probably still do it this way instead, which doesn't require any new extensions:

```
let badContents = Set(["b1", "b2"])

func filteredThings() -> [Thing] {
    return things.filter { $0.contents.first(where: { badContents.contains($0) }) == nil }
}
```

Even if you keep your approach, I'd stop searching when you found a collision. Finding all the collisions and then checking `.count == 0` is just kind of wasteful without being particularly easier to read.

Alternately, while a little less efficient in time and space, the following IMO is extremely explicit:

```
let badContents = Set(["b1", "b2"])

func filteredThings2() -> [Thing] {
    return things.filter { Set($0.contents).intersection(badContents).isEmpty }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func filteredThings() -> [Thing] {
    return things.filter({ (thing) -> Bool in {
        return arrayOfCommonElements(lhs: thing.contents, rhs: badContents).count == 0
    }()
    })
}
func arrayOfCommonElements <T, U> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element] where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
    var returnArray:[T.Iterator.Element] = []
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                returnArray.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
    return returnArray
}
```