# Array filter with aggregate operators

Tags: swift, nsarray, nspredicate

`array.filtered` does not exist in Swift anymore, I am looking for a way to use 'IN' operator in array.filter closure same as how I used it with NSPredicate.

Before the query was something like

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(user in %@)", overallUsers)
tasksArray.filtered(using: predicate)
```

Now this cannot be used with swift4, so how can I achieve the same with array.filter{} ? I tried something like this

```
tasksArray.filter{$0.user in overallUsers}
```

This fails with error 'Cannot convert value of type '@lvalue User' to closure result type 'Bool''. How this should be actually done ?

Comment: You want to filter overallUsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of common elements of 2 array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439289/how-to-get-list-of-common-elements-of-2-array-in-swift)

Comment: You can't translate word for word a `NSPredicate` format. You have to ask you this: "What means "something in someArray" in a NSPredicate"? If someArray contains something. Then, just write the corresponding "Swift" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it like this.

```
taskArray.filter( { overallUsers.contains($0.user) } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tasksArray.filter{$0.user in overallUsers}` you need something like this:

```
tasksArray.filter { task in
    overallUsers.contains(task.user)
}
```

Requirement: `User` has to conform to `Equatable`.